# Как достать значение с объекта

Tags: php, json, api, mailgun

Помогите, пожалуйста, достать и вывести значение [smtp] с объекта:

```
Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponse Object
(
    [start:Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponse:private] => DateTimeImmutable Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-04-13 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [end:Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponse:private] => DateTimeImmutable Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-04-13 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [resolution:Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponse:private] => day
    [stats:Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponse:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponseItem Object
                (
                    [time:Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponseItem:private] => DateTimeImmutable Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2020-04-13 00:00:00.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 3
                            [timezone] => UTC
                        )

                    [accepted:Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponseItem:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [delivered:Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponseItem:private] => Array
                        (
                            [smtp] => 2
                            [http] => 0
                            [optimized] => 0
                            [total] => 2
                        )

                    [failed:Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponseItem:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [complained:Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponseItem:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: смотрите методы доступа к полю `stats`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае простым обращением не получится решить проблему, поскольку `stats` является приватным свойством. Для получения данных `stats` вам надо посмотреть как реализован геттер у класса `Mailgun\Model\Stats\TotalResponseItem`. Если его нет, то внутри вы можете самостоятельно написать его. Примерно так будет выглядеть (самая простая интерпретация):

```
public function __get($property) {
return $this->$$property;
}
```

Теперь вы можете обратиться к приватному методу. Чтобы показывались они в выпадающем списке вашего редактора, надо прописать перед классов `class ... {}` документацию в формате PHPDoc. Для этого можете прочитать про [property](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html)

Comment: спасибо за помощь!